# AWS amplify (cognito) - change phone number during signup and verification

Tags: flutter, mobile, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have the "happy path" of signing up a user implemented using Flutter & AWS Amplify. I have made the user to verify their account using their phone numbers so that the verification code is sent to the phone and the signup process is completed.

I realised that, during testing, one could easily make a mistake. So I want the user to be able to go back and change the phone number so that the verification code is sent to the correct one. However, using Amplify, you cannot change the details if the user is not signed in, and the user cannot be signed in unless their account is "confirmed". Of course, their account cannot be "confirmed" if they don't receive the verification code and with the wrong phone number due to their mistake, they will never receive the verification code...

Has anyone faced the same problem and could help me how to solve this please?

I read that you could use Lambda functions to "auto-confirm" the account without any verification which means they can sign in, which would allow me to change their phone number if they have entered a wrong phone number. But I am not sure if this is the easiest way to do it

Comment: 1-Answer will be given based on personal opinion. 2-Not having reproduction code

Comment: I think what can be done is that you can add a "Change Phone Number" button that when they click, you remove any accounts with that email in Cognito and have them go through the signup process again. I am not sure if this %100 doable because I haven't checked Cognito and Amplify for some time.

Comment: Thank you @eytireyup, I also thought about this, but with flutter, you can only delete the user if you are logged in as that user... What I have done for now is to give the user a pop-up dialog to double-check their details...

Comment: Why not just have them write their phone number twice?

Comment: @Luke that's also a good idea! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to follow these steps to ensure their mobile number is correct with Cognito:

1. Have a regex pattern on the front-end determine whether the phone number is valid
2. Have them write their phone number in twice
3. Be very clear that if they have not received a text message, they should check their phone number and retry